# Which way of working with files is better: 'r' + 'a' or 'r+'?

Tags: python, performance, file

I'm working with a text file. I read it, then perform some actions and then write into it.

There's actually no problem here, but I'm curious about the performance.

I can do this:

```py
start = end = 0
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read()
'''
A bunch of code.
For example, working with "text" and getting "start" and "end"
'''
with open('test.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write(text[start:end])
```

or I can do this:

```py
start = end = 0
with open('test.txt', 'r+') as file:
    text = file.read()
    '''
    The exact same bunch of code. But the file is opened, that's what concerns me.
    '''
    file.write(text[start:end])
```

Which way is better in terms of performance?

Comment: why not use the timeit module and figure out yourself?

Comment: Since, you intend to write to the same file, the second approach is more readable and requires less code. You can time both versions and compare the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be heavily OS and filesystem dependent. I'd *guess* that the `r+` option is going to be (marginally) faster because it avoids creating an extra file-handle, but OS-level caching can easily smooth over the differences.

However, any difference is going to be so small as to *not matter*, in the face of everything else. I/O is slow, no matter what. The added cost of one more file object being created is not going to be noise in the normal variability in I/O timings.

Take into account that when you use the `r` / `a` pattern, that on most platforms files opened for append are explicitly blocked from overwriting data before the end. This protects you from bugs with seek that accidentally end up overwriting the wrong parts.

Comment: Yes, timeit shows the second one is a little bit faster. Thank you for a detailed response!

Comment: @HeavenlyRaven: run your tests several times, and reverse or randomise their order. Even better: use a large, randomised list of filenames (you may have to generate files up front, then use `next(fname_iterator)` in tests to give each individual test a new filename to work with). OS caches could easily make the second operation faster after the first has been tested.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you do with the file, since you need to read and write on the specified file, I would suggest using `r+`. (`r+` is has both reading mode and writing mode at the same time. This allows you to read and write into files at the same time without having to use `r` and `w`)

Answer (score -1):

The second one is better because you are opening the file just once. I do not know what you want to do with `file.write(text[start:end])` but be careful, `start = end = 0` so finally you are appending nothing to the file.

Comment: Why is opening the file once "better"?

Comment: Because you are creating just one file object

Comment: And you are keeping the one file open for an extended period of time, tying up a limited system resource for no reason other than to avoid re-opening the file when you actually need it.